# Automatically setting the time in Windows Phone 8.1 without SIM-card

Tags: 8.1, settings

According to [this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-81-update-1-lets-you-set-time-without-sim), since Windows Phone 8.1 you don't need a SIM-card in your phone to have it automatically adjust the built-in clock, since 8.1 supports NTP for this purpose, not just using the GSM network's time, which previous versions were limited to.

This does not work for me, and I seem to have that problem in common with a lot of the people commenting on that article. I do have an option under Date & Time "Set automatically" which is enabled (and I have switched that option back and forth several times, to no avail).

Everything else network-related works as expected, with one exception: software updates fail because my clock is out of sync (updating from 8.0 to 8.1 worked with the same clock settings but after that it is a dead end). Any workaround?

What am I and a lot of the people commenting doing wrong?

Comment: The article refers to update 1 of 8.1 (which is delivered as part of the Denim update on Nokia phones) - do you know which version of the OS you have installed?

Comment: Please provide the version number in `Settings` -> `About` -> `More Info` -> `OS Version`